# jquery insertafter() is not working in $(this) variable

Tags: jquery

jquery `insertafter()` is not working in `$(this)` variable.

My coding is here

```
<select name="input_field[]" class="selectcase">
        <option value="">Select</option>    
        <option value="input">Text</option> 
        <option value="option">Option</option>  
</select>
```

Script

```
$(this).change(function (){         
    $("<div><input type='text' name=''></div>").insertAfter($(this));           
});
```

I have many select tag and choose particular select tag. Using change function, I want to add textbox after select tag. I used `insertAfter()` function. But it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use `this` as id in first line, must be replaced with `select` :

```
$('select').change(function (){         
    $("<div><input type='text' name=''></div>").insertAfter($(this));           
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` would be `window` in your case, So you should bind the event using class name

```
$('.selectcase').change(function (){         
    $("<div><input type='text' name=''></div>").insertAfter($(this));           
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58ck6zbk/)

Answer (score 1):

When bind event `$(this)` refers to the `window`. You need to use correct selector i.e. `$(".selectcase")` instead of `$(this)` to listen for change event of the `select`

```
$(".selectcase").change(function (){         
    $("<div><input type='text' name=''></div>").insertAfter($(this));           
});
```